# Registration error messages

Tags: php, if-statement, registration

In my registration page when you forget to fill your username you receives this message:  **"Please insert a username"**, when you forget to fill the password then you receives this message: **"Please insert a password"** or when you forget to fill the email then you receives this message: **"Please insert a email"** as you can see in the code bellow.

```
<?php
include"header"

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(($username) == ""){
    ?><p><?php echo "Please insert a username"; ?></p><?php
}
if(($password) == ""){
    ?><p><?php echo "Please insert a password"; ?></p><?php
}
if(($email) == ""){
    ?><p><?php echo "Please insert a email"; ?></p><?php
}
else{

    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1){
        ?><p><?php echo "Username already exists"; ?></p><?php
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) == 1){
        ?><p><?php echo "Email already exists"; ?></p><?php
    }
    else{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());
        ?><p><?php echo "You are Registered"; ?></p><?php
    }
}
}

?>
<div id="loginform">
    <form name="loginform" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="0" id="tb">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div class="loginheader"><h2>Register</h2></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" id="REGOPTIONS">
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" class="text" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Email:</td>
            <td><input type="email" class="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td class="field"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="register" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

But my registration page can only display one error message at a time. I need my page to display all of them at once if you forget to fill your informations (username, password and email) at the same time like that:

**"Please insert a username"

"Please insert a password"

"Please insert a email"**

Comment: It is showing on my testing

Comment: The code is correct.There must be something wrong in form.Can you post the code of form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transformed into an array. Try:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["register"])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1){
        ?><p><?php echo "Username already exists"; ?></p><?php
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) == 1){
        ?><p><?php echo "Email already exists"; ?></p><?php
    }
    else{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());
        ?><p><?php echo "You are Registered"; ?></p><?php
    }
} else{

    if(empty($username)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a username";
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a password";
    }
    if(empty($email)){
        $error[] = "Please insert a email";
    }

    foreach ($error as $value) {
        echo "Erros: $value<br />\n";
    }
}
}
?>
<div id="loginform">
    <form name="loginform" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="0" id="tb">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div class="loginheader"><h2>Register</h2></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" id="REGOPTIONS">
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" class="text" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Email:</td>
            <td><input type="email" class="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td class="field"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="register" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working but i'm receiving this message: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Thanks, i'm not receiving errors. The only problem here is that you can register a username already registered using a new email.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is run through my form validation, and save each error (is there is one) to an array.

ie

```
$la_errors = array();

if(($username) == ""){
     $la_errors[] = "Please insert username";
}

//etc. Then
if(!empty($la_errors)) {
     break;
}
```

When you need to display the errors, explode the array, and display in a format (like

or whatever) of your choice

Comment: You got it. But copied and pasted this code and nothing happened. Something is missing?

Comment: i misspelt the variable name in the validation part. Have just added the 's'

Comment: Now the html part is in the question too.